# Picturebox location for X and Y is different then what is being entered in properties

Tags: c#

I have 2 picture box's, a hero and an enemy. The hero seems to load fine at the location I specify in the properties of the PictureBox (0,0). However, the enemy picture box I want it to be set to location (90,90), which I do set it to that, but when I run the windows form - for some reason - it is showing the picture form is at location (60,58).

The hero PictureBox is the Green and the Enemy is Orange.

I am wanting to make a simple game and want to move the hero the exact size as the tile he is so that if you move the hero to where the enemy is they should stack up flat on top of each other. I have my form set to a full size of (300,300) and both picture boxes are a size of (30,30). So, they should be able to "move" 10 moves to the left and right - if they are set at a starting position of (0,0). I am not sure if it is my movement method that is messing me up but I also have zero ideas as to why the location of x and y are different when I tried to post it to console to debug this situation- instead of being 90,90 where I placed it on the form and in properties. Ideally I should be able to move 3 to the left and 3 down and be on top of the enemy but it's not at all correct.

Is there any reason why these are not the same? I will attach photos and my source code.

---

Starting Position

[image]

Hero Moving - They are not directly on top of each other but should be

[image]

Enemy Properties - to show size and location

[image]

Hero Properties - to show size and location

[image]

CODE

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Mirage
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
Random rand = new Random();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Console.WriteLine("HERO STARTING LOCATION --- X = : {0} ---- Y = : {1}", pctrBxHero.Location.X, pctrBxHero.Location.Y);
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (Font myFont = new Font("Lucida", 10))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString("@", myFont, Brushes.Green, new Point(0, 0));
    }
}

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    int x = pctrBxHero.Location.X;
    int y = pctrBxHero.Location.Y;

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) x += 30;
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) x -= 30;
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) y -= 30;
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) y += 30;

    pctrBxHero.Location = new Point(x, y);
    Console.WriteLine("HERO --- X = : {0} ---- Y = : {1}", x, y);
    Console.WriteLine("ENEMY --- X = : {0} ---- Y = : {1}", pctrBxEnemy.Location.X, pctrBxEnemy.Location.Y);
}

private void pictureBox2_Paint_1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{

    using (Font myFont = new Font("Lucida", 10))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString("X", myFont, Brushes.Orange, new Point(0, 0));
    }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of massive confusion I have fixed my problem. It turns out it was a scaling issue.

I had my form `AutoScaleMode` property set to `"Font"`- which is the default setting.

That was scaling my picture boxes down and scaling my form down. I believe the issue was so major is because I am using a laptop and a 24" monitor. I was running the program on my secondary monitor (the 24") and it was producing a warped result.

It seems as that building stuff by pixels, now-a-days, is less effective/attractive because of high Dpi screens.

Once I switched the form `AutoScaleMode` to `Dpi` the results did in fact yield a true 300x300 and my picture box's are exactly where they should be.

This is a tad annoying and took me awhile to realize but hopefully this will help someone else.

I am still not exactly sure as to ***why*** the pixels/frame would not show up as the 300x300 like I specified in the properties but it is now resolved. I would love to know why if anyone knows.

---

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm unable to reproduce your problem in my example project.

Here's my output:

```
HERO --- X = : 30 ---- Y = : 0
ENEMY --- X = : 90 ---- Y = : 90
HERO --- X = : 60 ---- Y = : 0
ENEMY --- X = : 90 ---- Y = : 90
HERO --- X = : 90 ---- Y = : 0
ENEMY --- X = : 90 ---- Y = : 90
HERO --- X = : 90 ---- Y = : 30
ENEMY --- X = : 90 ---- Y = : 90
HERO --- X = : 90 ---- Y = : 60
ENEMY --- X = : 90 ---- Y = : 90
HERO --- X = : 90 ---- Y = : 90
ENEMY --- X = : 90 ---- Y = : 90
```

With a screenshots at start and after moving:

[image]

[image]

The code I used:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Font fnt = new Font("Lucida", 10);

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        int x = pctrBxHero.Location.X;
        int y = pctrBxHero.Location.Y;

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) x += 30;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) x -= 30;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) y -= 30;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) y += 30;

        pctrBxHero.Location = new Point(x, y);

        Console.WriteLine("HERO --- X = : {0} ---- Y = : {1}", x, y);
        Console.WriteLine("ENEMY --- X = : {0} ---- Y = : {1}", pctrBxEnemy.Location.X, pctrBxEnemy.Location.Y);
    }

    private void pctrBxHero_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    { 
        e.Graphics.DrawString("@", fnt, Brushes.Green, new Point(0, 0));
    }

    private void pctrBxEnemy_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString("X", fnt, Brushes.Orange, new Point(0, 0));
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        fnt.Dispose();
    }

}
```

I notice that you have "pictureBox2_Paint_1", which means you renamed the PictureBox after wiring it up, and also that you possibly had two Paint() events at one point (since it added the "_1" on the end).  It's possible that you simply need to start over with fresh PictureBoxes; delete your existing ones, add new ones, rename them, then set their properties back up.  Finally, select each one, click on the "Lightning Bolt" icon to see their events, and re-wire up their Paint() events.

********** EDIT **********

Here's an alternate approach that may get around your scaling problem.  Get rid of the PictureBoxes altogether and **DRAW** both your Hero and Enemy in the Paint() event of your Form.  This could look something like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center; // vertical center
        sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center; // horizontal center
    }

    private int boxSize = 30;
    private bool EnemyKilled = false;
    private Point pntHero = new Point(0, 0);
    private Point pntEnemy = new Point(3, 3);
    private Font fnt = new Font("Lucida", 10);
    private StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) pntHero.Offset(1,0);
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) pntHero.Offset(-1, 0);
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) pntHero.Offset(0, -1);
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) pntHero.Offset(0, 1);

        if (pntHero.Equals(pntEnemy))
        {
            EnemyKilled = true;
        }

        this.Invalidate();

        Console.WriteLine("HERO: " + pntHero.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("ENEMY: " + pntEnemy.ToString());
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle rc;

        rc = new Rectangle(new Point(pntEnemy.X * boxSize, pntEnemy.Y * boxSize), new Size(boxSize, boxSize));
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.White, rc);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(EnemyKilled ? "X" : "O", fnt, Brushes.Orange, (RectangleF)rc, sf);

        rc = new Rectangle(new Point(pntHero.X * boxSize, pntHero.Y * boxSize), new Size(boxSize, boxSize));
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.White, rc);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("@", fnt, Brushes.Green, (RectangleF)rc, sf);
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        fnt.Dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you. You are right but I think the reason you are right and, I believe the main reason, this is happening is a scaling issue. Look at your picture box sizes compared to my screenshots above. After messing around with this for over an hour I know the reason why.

Comment: Check the bottom half of my post, below the "EDIT" line, for an alternate approach.

Answer (score 0):

Btw, the properties for the pctrBxEnemy, under the behavior section shows CenterImage. It may reposition your picture box as CenterImage tries to position the image in the center of the client area.

I tried to load your project. It is weird that the position of that enemy is 60,58. Nonetheless, you could override it in the code whilst initialising (as below). Now, when I press 3 down and 3 right - the box completely overlaps.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Console.WriteLine("HERO STARTING LOCATION --- X = : {0} ---- Y = : {1}", pctrBxHero.Location.X, pctrBxHero.Location.Y);
        pctrBxEnemy.Location = new Point(90, 90);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I up voted because I did not realize that had gotten altered. It did not however fix my issue but I appreciate the help!

Comment: It will only affect the image, not the pbox.

Comment: Updated the answer... to force positioning of the enemy picture box. I'm puzzled too now, lol.